# How to remove proxy permanently from ubuntu>

Tags: proxy, removing

How to remove proxy permanently from Ubuntu?
I tried the following but each time I restart it shows up and I have to rerun the command.

```
env|grep proxy 
while read var; do unset $var; done < <(env | grep -i proxy | awk -F= '!/no_proxy/{print $1}')
```

Comment: What proxy variable is being set, exactly?

Comment: The command in the bracket shows the proxy value set(env|grep proxy)