# How to remove http proxy for git?

Tags: 16.04, networking, proxy, git

I can't get rid of a proxy configured in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried the solutions suggested here, but did not resolved my situation:

[How to permanently disable http_proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251003/how-to-permanently-disable-http-proxy)

[How to disable proxy in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956755/how-to-disable-proxy-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

[How to remove proxy permanently from ubuntu>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916262/how-to-remove-proxy-permanently-from-ubuntu)

The command `env | grep proxy` return nothing.

The network setting GUI is configured to `None` and `Applied system wide`.

I have removed the line of the proxy from `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, now is empty. Already rebooted the system (note: shut-down then power on, not just pressed *reboot*).

I have removed git and installed again but no luck.

If try to clone a repository from git, i still get errors because of the system is trying to connect to the proxy (i have not copied the github url and proxy ip in clear):

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.git

Cloning into 'xxxxxxx'...
fatal: unabke to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.git/': Failed to connect to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX port 8080: Connection timed out.
```

I i run apt command, for example `apt-get update` it does not try to connect to the proxy, and work properly.

How can i remove this proxy? Thank you

Comment: Is it perhaps a git specific proxy? does anything show up in `git config -l` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `git config -l` returned:

```
http.proxy=http://@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
http.proxyauthmethod=basic
http.sslverify=false
```

So it's a git specific proxy. Resolved by the command:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Now `git config -l` return:

```
http.proxyauthmethod=basic
http.sslverify=false
```

And `git clone` works properly.